# How to place custom image onto QMessageBox

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qmessagebox

[image]

---

Clicking "Submit" button brings a `QMessageBox` with three response buttons. 'Critical', 'Information', 'Question', 'Warning' boxes each have their icon. Is there a way to customize the icon on QMessageBox?

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.resize(300, 100)
        self.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())

        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Submit')
        button.clicked.connect(self.onclick)
        self.layout().addWidget(button)

    def onclick(self):
        self.close()
        messagebox = QtGui.QMessageBox(QtGui.QMessageBox.Warning, "Title text", "body text", buttons = QtGui.QMessageBox.Discard | QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel | QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok, parent=self)
        messagebox.setDefaultButton(QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel)
        exe = messagebox.exec_()
        print 'messagebox.exec_(): %s'%exe    



dialog = Dialog()
dialog.show()     
app.exec_()
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After creating the `QMessageBox`, just call `messagebox.setIconPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/image_file))` where `image_file` is the path to your image resource.

Comment: May want to edit the answer to include the closing quote for your relative path incase someone inexperienced copies this to try it. It should be `messagebox.setIconPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/image_file"))` Can't edit it myself because it's less than 6 characters.